# Complete and Generate number for a array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I'm looking to complete one numbers, you can help me generate a array of please.
The first 4 digits start by "23 29 xx xx xx", the xx remains to be completed with a range from 0 to 99. Ex. 23 29 01 02 03

```
let firstDigit = "2329";
let numberOfRandomDigit = "6";
let firstRange = "01";
let maxRange = "99";
let arrayOfNumbers = ["2329010203, 2329xxxxxx", ...];
```

I don't know to do this with a loop for complete array

Comment: Which language? JS or Python? Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Yes sorry i need in JS, error during complete tag

Answer (score 1):

as I see it's a 10 digit number, and you know 4 digits initial, so rest 6 digits you can generate randomly like this :

```
from random import randint

def random_num(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

rest_digit = random_num(6)
```

Now you can simply append these 6 digit to the 4 digits that you have.

Comment: Yes sorry for you invest i need in JS, error of tag during post

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```js
let firstDigit = "2329";
let firstRange = "00";
let maxRange = "99";

var random_string = function(digits) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRange-firstRange+1)+firstRange).toString();
    while (num.length < digits)
        {
            num = "0" + num;
        }
    return num;
}

var arrayOfNumbers = [];
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    six_digit_string = random_string(2)+random_string(2)+random_string(2);
    arrayOfNumbers.push(firstDigit+six_digit_string);
}
```

In Python:

```py
import random

def random_two_digit_numbers():
    return str(random.randint(0,99)).zfill(2)

generated_string = '23 29 {} {} {}'.format(random_two_digit_numbers,random_two_digit_numbers,random_two_digit_numbers)
```

Comment: Yes sorry for you invest i need in JS, error of tag during post

Comment: @NevadaStone I added JS snippet to the answer

Comment: Nice job ! Thx you